# removing the double [] inside a appended list

Tags: python, list

I have the following:

```
def fun(data):
    ...do some processing
    ret_data = ['a','b','c']
    return ret_data

l1 = []
l1.append(fun(data))
```

Output:

```
l1 is [['a','b','c']]
```

I don't want to create another list and unpack it to it.  I want to use l1 but with the extra [] removed so that the output is:

Need:

```
l1=['a','b','c']
```

having a difficult time with this...

Comment: Why not just `l1 = fun(data)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Python's list methods append and extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `list.extend`:

```
def fun():
    # ...do some processing
    ret_data = ['a','b','c']
    return ret_data

l1 = []
l1.extend(fun())

print(l1)
```

Prints:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 3):

If the code looks exactly like that and you create `l1` before appending you don't need to set `l1 = []` you can just set `l1` to the return value of the function, like this: `l1 = fun(data)`.